# How i can use jooq with javers?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jooq

I want use javers with jooq/Spring but i don`t know how, how i can implement it?. I need Auditable repository with Spring/jooq stack. I have tried javers with spring-data-jpa, but it is not my way.